# LD_BIND_NOW doesn’t seem to take effect on ELF PIE executable?

Tags: elf, pie

**Observations**

When the Linux executable is compiled as PIE (Position Independent Executable, default on Ubuntu 18.04), the symbols from shared libraries (e.g. libc) will be resolved when the program starts executing, setting LD_BIND_NOW environment variable to null will not defer this process.

However, if the executable is compiled with the `-no-pie` flag, the symbol resolution can be controlled by LD_BIND_NOW.

**Question**

Is it possible to control when the symbols from share libraries to be resolved on a ELF PIE executable?

Below is the test code and system info,

```
ubuntu: 18.04
kernel: Linux 4.15.0-50-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 18:46:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
gcc: gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0


$ gcc -o helloworld helloworld.c

$ file helloworld
helloworld: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=70143fcc329797b2d0af84143ce0125775ab330f, not stripped

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible while compiling with `clang`**: `clang -o helloworld helloworld.c`. To test it, run:

```
export LD_DEBUG=reloc,symbols
./helloWorld
```

with `LD_BIND_NOW` null and then with `LD_BIND_NOW` equal `1`. You will see that in the first case the call to `printf` is indeed being resolved at demand, and in the second case it will be resolved before transferring control to the program.

```
LD_BIND_NOW=null
```

[image: LD_BIND_NOW_NULL]

```
LD_BIND_NOW=1
```

[image: LD_BIND_NOW_1]

It doesn't work for `GCC` for some reason, as you have noticed, at least without specifying relevant options.